# PHPmailer envía correo duplicado

Tags: php, android-studio, webservice, phpmailer

Hola estoy usando la libreria volley desde android studio para realizar peticiones https y poder enviar emails usando PHPmailer, el problema es que recibo en el destinatario el email duplicado, llevo horas intentando resolver el problema y no sé por qué pasa, no tengo bucles ni en android ni en php intente el metodo clearadresses() de phpmailer, tambien intente usar exit(); y aun no he podido solucionar el inconveniente. Aqui dejaré los códigos del script.php y del android studio. Espero me ayuden a solucionar el problema

**Fragmento Android Studio**

```
public void enviarCorreo(String URL){
    String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();

    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setMessage("Validando usuario...");
    pd.show();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.equals("correctamente")){
                pd.hide();
                AlertDialog.Builder a = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                a.setMessage("Se ha enviado un correo electrónico a " + Email + " con sus datos de acceso");
                a.setCancelable(false);
                a.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                a.show();
            } else if(response.equals("inexistente")){
                pd.hide();
                AlertDialog.Builder a = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                a.setMessage("El correo electrónico ingresado no existe");
                a.setCancelable(false);
                a.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                a.show();
            } else {
                pd.hide();
                AlertDialog.Builder a = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                a.setMessage("Hubo un error al validar: " + response);
                a.setCancelable(false);
                a.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                a.show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            pd.hide();
            AlertDialog.Builder a = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            a.setMessage("Error: " + error.toString());
            a.setCancelable(false);
            a.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            a.show();
        }
    }){
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map parametros = new HashMap();
            parametros.put("correo", Email);
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    queue.add(request);
}
```

**Script php**

```
$email = $_POST['correo'];
if($email == ''){
    echo "Campos vacios";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '$email'";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta) > 0){
    
    $dato = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

    $body = '<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; width: 370px; margin: auto; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; font-family:adobe-clean,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;"> <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3616/3616459.png" style="width: 36px;"> &nbsp; <strong>JotaTuts</strong></p>
        <table style="width: 370px; margin: auto;  border-top-left-radius: 30px; border-top-right-radius: 30px; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px; overflow: hidden; magin: 0; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
            <tbody style="">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="https://img.freepik.com/vector-gratis/contrasena-acceso-seguro-aviso-acceso-o-codigo-verificacion-autenticacion-nota-mensaje-burbuja-icono-voz-plana-dibujos-animados_212005-104.jpg?size=626&amp;ext=jpg&amp;ga=GA1.2.1290984231.1628629898" style="magin: 0;  width: 370px;  border-top-left-radius: 30px;border-top-right-radius: 30px;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="font-size: 29px; font-family:adobe-clean,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; line-height:40px;">
                    <td><strong>Recuperacion de datos de acceso.</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-family: adobe-clean,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; padding-top:16px; line-height: 20px; font-size: 17px;">Estimado usuario: hemos recibido una solicitud para la recuperacion de sus datos de acceso, a continuacion se muestra toda su informacion:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=" padding-bottom: 10px;font-family:adobe-clean,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; padding-top:16px; line-height: 25px; font-size: 17px;"><strong>Usuario:</strong> '.$dato['usuario'].' <br> <strong>Contraseña:</strong> '.$dato['contrasena'].'</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; width: 450px; margin: auto; margin-top: 20px; font-family:adobe-clean,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;">Correo generado automaticamente, no responder. <br> Este correo fue generado por JotaTuts. Si lo recibio por error haga caso omiso. <br> JotaTuts todo los derechos reservados &copy;</p>';

        //Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        try {
            //Server settings
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      //Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
            $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username   = '**********';                     //SMTP username
            $mail->Password   = '*********';                               //SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
            $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('*******', '******');
            $mail->addAddress($email);     //Add a recipient
            

            //Attachments
            // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
            // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

            //Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Recuperacion de datos de acceso | JotaTuts';
            $mail->Body    = $body;
            $mail->AltBody = 'Su lector de email no puede leer este mensaje.\n\nPóngase em contato con *********';

            $mail->send();
            $mail->clearAddresses();
            echo "correctamente";
            exit;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }

   } else {
    echo "inexistente";
   }
}
```

> He puesto los datos confidenciales con asteriscos (*)

Comment: tienes 2 onclick, por que no separas en una clase aparte en envio de correros y en el debug le pones un breakpoint asi te das cuenta si se esta disparando dos veces el envio de correo desde la app, desde el php todo lo veo regular.